# Proving $\frac{\sin b+\sin c}{2} < \sin\frac{b+c}{2}$ using only the graph of $\sin x$

Tags: geometry

> How to prove that
> $$\frac{\sin b+\sin c}{2} < \sin\frac{b+c}{2}$$ using *only* the graph of $\sin(x)$?

I just tried to construct some triangles and see where it would leave me. But I don't know what to persued to prove this statement.

Thinking that it would be easier to prove it by absurd, I created this:

[image]

The two pink triangle would be the triangles that does not violate our statement, while the triangles connecting to the purple dot (located at $((b+c)/2,(\sin(b)+\sin(c))/2)$) would not be allowed. Please think the points as a doublet in the cartesian $(x,y)$, that is, they are not just points without coordinates "floating" in the space.

But the main problem is that I can't see any violation in the green/orange triangle. In fact I am almost sure that my drawing is useless... But if not by triangles, what could I use to prove the statement?

Comment: The set-theoretic definition of a function is that it is a special kind of set of ordered pairs, so a function IS its graph. So I don't know what is intended by "using only its graph" .

Comment: @DanielWainfleet probably the author wants we solve the problem only by geometric means...

Comment: The proposition is actually false. Consider $b = \pi$, $c = 2\pi$. I expect that it is true if you put in modulus signs (or restrict the domain).

Comment: I would say that the geometric properties of the graph can only be deduced from properties of the function. E.g. You can show the 2nd derivative of $\sin x$ is negative for $x\in (0,\pi /2]$, implying the graph is strictly concave on that part. If you replace $\sin$ with something else, you will have to examine the function's properties to start.

Answer (score 2):

$(\sin(b)+\sin(c))/2$ is the midpoint (on the y-axis) of $\sin(b)$ and $\sin(c)$.  $(b+c)/2$ is the midpoint of $b$ and $c$ (on the x-axis).  So find the two midpoints and see how the $\sin$ values compare.

Answer (score 1):

An elementary trigonometric solution. Let $M=(b+c)/2$ and $D=(b-c)/2.$ Then $$\sin b+\sin c=\sin (M+D)+\sin (M-D)=$$ $$=(\sin M\cos D+\cos M\sin D)+(\sin M\cos D-\cos M\sin D)=$$ $$=2\sin M\cos D=2\sin\left(\frac {b+c}{2}\right)\cos D.$$ Now if $b,c\in [0,\pi]$ and $b\ne c$ then $\sin(\frac {b+c}{2})>0$ and $\cos D<1$, implying $$2\sin\left(\frac {b+c}{2}\right)\cos D<2\sin\left(\frac {b+c}{2}\right).$$

Comment: The identity $\sin b +\sin c=2\sin M\cos D$ has many applications.